# Drobo Pro or SAN for backups

Tags: backup, rsync, storage-area-network, drobo

I have multiple offices and was thinking of using two Drobo Pros as a storage location for my backups, with one at each site being synced.  It seems like on the surface its a cheap alternative to a SAN.  Because it will just be used for storing backups I don't think that performance is as big of an issue.

Related question.
How do you sync your backups from your main location to a remote site.  I am using Backup Exec and wondered if I should use a feature in the program or use something like Delta Copy.

Comment: Drobo is an awesome option :) i use it myself and love it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider rolling your own NAS machine. Its not overly hard and is pretty cost effective. That said the drobo is nice, but consider your options for disaster recovery also. As i understand it the drobo uses its own form of raid ? - how would this impact rebuilding the volume if the drobo breaks ?

If performance isnt a major concern, consumer grade hardware and a decent backup policy (raid alone isnt backup remember) should keep things safe.

In terms of sync, to be honest rsync has always done the job. Perhaps taking lvm snapshots of the array may work, or sometimes backula or similar may be the solution.

Comment: http://support.datarobotics.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/150 you can just put it all into another drobo and it will be ready to use. You can also transfer / migrate disks.

Comment: this is true, but youre locking into buying more products from the same company, when better, cheaper, more flexible, and more robust solutions exist.